# Show unnecessary usings in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, using

I programing in C# using Visual studio 2010. Is it possible to make it show me which usings 
are not used in code?

Comment: Not sure if VS will do this but there are third party plugins like coderush that will.

Comment: Resharper could do the trick as well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This must help you... right click mouse on the vs [image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Right Click -> Organize Usings -> Remove Unused Usings
```